# Circular dependency and graphs

Tags: c++, design-patterns, data-structures

Should circular dependency be avoided on graphs ?

For instance, consideer a `graph` class embedding an array of `vertex` objects, each of them having an array of `edge` objects which point to a `vertex`.

Here, `vertex` and `edge` are circularly dependent. Is this a bad idea ? Should it and how could it be avoided ?

Comment: often an `edge` will use identifiers for each `vertex` and not use pointers to each `vertex`. The `graph` will contain the edges as well as the vertices.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x : How is it beneficial to use identifiers rather than pointers, except for avoiding circular dependency ?

Comment: It all depends on the context of how your graph is going to be used. If you need an `edge` object to be standalone and not tied to the graph itself then you need to use pointers to the vertices. However, if your graph class stores vertices in an `vector` and supports adding vertices then you can't use pointers because they can move.

Comment: @vu1p3nox : well you still can just old an array of edge I don't get what is the problem with a pointer. A pointer is just like an identifier.

Comment: again, its all dependent on how `graph` is used. If you can guarantee that vertices aren't going to `move` then I don't see anything wrong with using pointers. In fact, using pointers can make some things easier.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x : Then, I shouldn't bother about the fact that it is said to be an antipattern?

Comment: The reason it is an anti-pattern is because it makes the destruction of objects more complicated in that you need to make sure you clean up all other references. In contrast, a graph by-design has vertices depend on each other by way of edges so it can't really be avoided. Many "anti-patterns" do have their uses.

Comment: As @vu1p3n0x said, it's hard to avoid some kind of circular reference for graph-like structures.

It is something where locality matters though: leaking the responsibilities to delete objects correctly to code that uses your graph data structure would be a problem. But if you can provide trivial 'vertex' and 'edge' value-types that can be verified as 'good' against some internal representation of the 'graph' data structure, then you can make your data structure easier to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it shouldn't. Graphs that have a non-trivial edge and vertex classes are *inherently* circular-dependent. If `edge` is practically empty, you might just store the adjacency matrix (i.e., whether there's an edge between given vertices); if `vertex` is empty, you might store and edge list that stores vertex number (size_t) instead of pointer.
Best practice is to use smart_ptr<> and weak_ptr<> to break the chain. The latter is non-owning, thus:

- If your graph stores vertices:

  - `graph` class has `vector< smart_ptr< vertex > >`
  - `vertex` class has `vector< smart_ptr< edge > > m_out;` and optionally `vector< weak_ptr< edge > > m_in;`
  - `edge` class has `weak_ptr< vertex > m_vertices[2];` (or better yet m_from and m_to)
- If your graph stores edges:

  - `graph` class has `vector< smart_ptr< edge > >`
  - `edge` class has `smart_ptr< vertex > m_from;` and `weak_ptr< vertex > m_to;`
  - `vertex` class has `vector< weak_ptr< edge > > m_out;` and optionally `vector< weak_ptr< edge > > m_in;`

If, for some reason (like widsom of senior :), coding standard, etc.) you cannot use smart_ptr<> and weak_ptr<>, you might use references instead of weak pointers, those are generally considered non-owning. Instead of smart_ptr<> you might either use pointers - or why not have members as long as `edge` and `vertex` are not base classes. Stroustrup additionally recommends marking naked pointers that should be deleted on exit using `owner<>`. If you don't have it, you might define a no-op for it as `template<typename T> using owner = T;`.